# Github pages doesn't show images on my website

Tags: image, github-pages

I put my website on github pages following [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-github-pages-to-host-your-website) website and it works fine. The problem is that when I put it online, four images of the homepage are not shown whereas locally yes.

The code I use for displaying it is

```
      <img src="img/prototyping.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

the source is here

[image]

The dimension is 521 x 521 for 180 KB.

I tried to put another picture that is on the homepage and another random picture and it shows up...

I looked up the console of each browser but no info about it.

Do you have an idea of any possible solution of it?

Comment: Without repository url it will be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it:

The problem was that the image was not exported in png from photoshop but only "Save as", html didn't like that. In order to export it in png format in photoshop I did File -> Export -> Quick export as PNG.
Thanks